# symfony 4 - form constraint - image not working

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, symfony4

I have the following code in my code builder (the relevant part):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image;
..................................................
$builder->add('image', FileType::class, [
    'required' => false,
    'constraints' => [
         new Image([
             'maxSize' => '2048k'
         ])
    ]
])
```

The form is created correctly and everything seems fine so far. Now, on submit, in controller I have the following code:

```
$form = $this->createForm(OrderReviewType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);


if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    dd($request->files);
}
```

When I upload an html file for example I expect validation to fail (constraint is Image). Instead form is validated. Dump below:

```
FileController.php on line 43:
FileBag^ {#15 ▼
  #parameters: array:1 [▼
    "order_review" => array:1 [▼
      "image" => UploadedFile^ {#16 ▼
        -test: false
        -originalName: "test.html"
        -mimeType: "text/html"
        -error: 0
        path: "/tmp"
        filename: "phpOPra8g"
        basename: "phpOPra8g"
        pathname: "/tmp/phpOPra8g"
        extension: ""
        realPath: "/tmp/phpOPra8g"
        aTime: 2019-07-02 12:51:24
        mTime: 2019-07-02 12:51:24
        cTime: 2019-07-02 12:51:24
        inode: 17041021
        size: 678
        perms: 0100600
        owner: 1000
        group: 1000
        type: "file"
        writable: true
        readable: true
        executable: false
        file: true
        dir: false
        link: false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Any idea why the constraint doesn't work? No errors occur.

Comment: Care to explain the -1?

Answer (score 0):

I've been to the [Symfony Documentation for Image Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html#basic-usage) and i haven't seen the maxSize Option.

It also specify that to ensure check if the Image is valid and a certain size you should use the: minWidth, maxWidth, minHeight, maxHeight options.

I'm just browsing the Symfony Documentation here but are you sur you are using the right options to constraint your Image ?

Comment: Image constraint extends file constraint that has a maxSize. From the docs: The Image constraint works exactly like the File constraint, except that its mimeTypes and mimeTypesMessage options are automatically setup to work for image files specifically.

Additionally it has options so you can validate against the width and height of the image.

See the File constraint for the bulk of the documentation on this constraint. And from code: class Image extends File, protected $maxSize;